# How to get JWT cookie in reactjs which is send by the server

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, setcookie, jwt

I am using reactjs on the client-side. The server is sending a cookie after authentication.

So my question is that How to get JWT cookie in react-js which is send by the server and how to manage a token on behalf of this cookie

Comment: You can get the cookie with `document.cookie` and go from there. You need a JWT library to parse the token to get at the information inside. You will not be able to verify that the token is valid in the frontend though but that should be ok depending on your use case; this is a library for decoding JWT tokens in the frontend: https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode

Comment: You need to check if the cookie is `httpOnly`, if it is, then there is no way to access the cookie from the client-side.

Comment: @kraf, In order to decode it first I need to get the cookie. I don't want to decode the cookie. And `document.cookie` is returning nothing.

Comment: @HarryChang, so how can I set the user is logged in and it's token is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, there will be an API for client-side to get the data of the current user, for instance, send a `GET` request to `/api/me` to get the user data `{ username: 'harry830622', /* email, gender, etc. */ }`.

In your scenario, the JWT is in the cookie, so it will be sent to the server in every request made by the browser automatically.
When the server receive the request, it will first verify the JWT in the cookie, if the JWT is correct, respond with the data, otherwise, throw an error of `401 UNAUTHORIZED`.

Therefore, to check if a user is logined or not, simply send a `GET` request to the API to see if the response has valid data.

Comment: I will try your solution. Thank you